# Rails find all with conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to search records on a Table based on an array of foreign key ids and trigger error if one of the ids doesn't exist, e.g.

```
pry(main)> Person.find([1, 2, 2002])

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find all Person 
with 'id': (1, 2, 2002) [WHERE "persons"."deleted_at" IS 
NULL] (found 2 results, but was looking for 3).
```

The problem is, the array of ids is not id, but parent_id which is a foreign key in Person. I want something like this, but it has deprecated:

```
Person.find(:all, :conditions => { :friends => ["Bob", "Steve", "Fred"] }
```

If I do like this,

```
Person.where(friends: ["Bob", "Steve", "Fred"])
```

it will just return 2 results instead of triggering error if Fred isn't found.

Thanks

Comment: What's the relationship between both tables?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find_by` method for column specific search.

```
Person.find_by(friends: ["Bob", "Steve", "Fred"])
```

Or

```
Person.find_by_friends(["Bob", "Steve", "Fred"])
```

Comment: still not what im looking for because Person.find_by! won't trigger error if Fred doesn't exist

Comment: I'm afraid, there is no possible solution with rails 6. you have to write custom exception if the number of elements in array doesn't match the result.